# Shipping price and Grand Total Excl Tax confusion

Tags: magento2, shipping, tax-calculation

Our shipping and tax & grand total (excl. tax) calculation are wrong. We have set shipping & handling fees to include tax via settings, but shipping still gets added to Grand Total (Excl. Tax).

See the following example (VAT here is 24%).

```
Subtotal                €141.05
Shipping & Handling     €7.90
Grand Total (Excl.Tax)  €148.95     (141.05+7.90 = 148.95)
Total Tax               €33.85      (141.05*0.24 = 33.85)
Grand Total (Incl.Tax)  €182.80
```

As you can see, shipping gets added to grand total excluding tax, but total tax is only calculated from the subtotal. What we want is to clearly display Grand Total (Excl. tax) + Total Tax + Shipping = Grand Total (Incl. Tax). How should we handle it?

Magento 2.3.2